# Problems with understanding actors in scala

Tags: scala, actor

I've been trying to understand actors in scala but I'm still not getting it...

The following code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]){

  while(true){
    println("inside main")
    MyActor ! "go"
  }

}

object MyActor extends Actor{
  def act(){
    loop{
      react{
        case _ => println("inside actor")
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

It is printing `inside main`, but not `inside actor`... Why? Moreover, what's the difference between receive and react??

Comment: The (dated) [Actor tutorial](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/242) does a fair job of explaining receive vs. react and the Actor library that comes with Scala in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actors need to be started.  Just add `MyActor.start` at the top of your main method and it will work.  It will be less messy if you add a delay inside your while loop.